# Password protect entire magento store

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm looking for a method of password protecting an entire magento store. Unfortunately i can't use the htpasswd method, as I have some external SOAP stuff going on that can't be updated to bypass this.

I also can't have it based on the standard magento user accounts, as I need the magento store to function as normal (sign up for individual accounts etc) once someone has entered in a global username and password.

Any thoughts?